# focus() not working after Popover closed in material ui

Tags: material-ui

I can't figure out why I can't programmatically focus an input html element (part of a Material UI TextField) once I've opened a Popover that steals the focus. I can programmatically focus before I open the Popover but once I close it then I can no longer programmatically focus the input element that belongs to the Textfield.

Can someone help me? I’m not able to use autoFocus on the Textfield because I’ve built it as part of a grid so I need a way to force focus programmatically back to the Textfield

Thanks,

Adam

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by making sure I always got the latest element when attempting to focus. Turns out I was trying to programmatically focus an element in the DOM that no longer existed after React re-rendered the component